# merge (base R) - unexpected result

Tags: r, join, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames using the `merge` function in R. The two dataframes are merging, by common column `advBucket`, however only the first factor in `advBucket` is present in the new dataframe, which I don't understand.

```
library("dplyr")
dmB <- c(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 30.0, 100.0, 200.0)
ordersDM$advBucket <- cut(ordersDM$adv, breaks=dmB, include.lowest=TRUE, right=TRUE)
temp1 <- summarize( group_by(ordersDM, advBucket),
                         eISmedian = median(is),
                         eISmean = mean(is))
orders1 <- merge(ordersDM, temp1, by = "advBucket", all=TRUE)
```

- `ordersDM` has expected output: all 14 buckets are present: `(0.0,0.5)` to `(100.0,200.0)`.
- `temp1` has the expected output: 14 rows x 3 columns.
- `orders1`, however, has the same number of rows as `ordersDM`, but

  - `orders1$adv` only has values between `0.0` and `0.5` and
  - `orders1$advBucket` only has the value `(0.0, 0.50)`.

I am confused as to why `merge` isn't working as expected: all `advBuckets` should be present in `orders1`, and `orders1$adv` shouldn't be different from `ordersDM$adv`.

```
str(ordersDM)
data.frame':    9343 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ desc     : Factor w/ 10770 levels "Order:864631",..: 2 11 12 15 18 19 ...
 $ adv      : num  97.51 8.08 44.25 38.25 35.48 ...
 $ advBucket: Factor w/ 14 levels "[0,0.5]","(0.5,1]",..: 13 9 13 13 13 6 ...

str(temp1)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   14 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ advBucket: Factor w/ 14 levels "[0,0.5]","(0.5,1]",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ eISmedian: num  0 -0.161 -4.817 -4.478 -19.447 ...
 $ eISmean  : num  -2.28 -6.18 -10.84 -16.41 -30.9 ...
- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE

str(orders1)
data.frame':    9343 obs. of  32 variables:
 $ advBucket: Factor w/ 14 levels "[0,0.5]","(0.5,1]",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ..
 $ desc     : Factor w/ 10770 levels "Order:864631",..
 $ adv      : num  0.567 0.632 0.942 0.914 0.589 ...
```

unexpected result: ordersDM$advBucket only contains (0.5,1] and ordersDM$adv only contains values between 0.5 and 1.0

```
identical( levels(ordersDM$advBucket), levels( temp1$advBucket) )
[1] TRUE

dput(head(ordersDM$advBucket))
structure(c(13L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 6L), .Label = c("[0,0.5]", 
"(0.5,1]", "(1,2]", "(2,3]", "(3,4]", "(4,5]", "(5,6]", "(6,8]", 
"(8,10]", "(10,15]", "(15,20]", "(20,30]", "(30,100]", "(100,200]"
), class = "factor")

dput(head(temp1))
structure(list(advBucket = structure(1:6, .Label = c("[0,0.5]", 
"(0.5,1]", "(1,2]", "(2,3]", "(3,4]", "(4,5]", "(5,6]", "(6,8]", 
"(8,10]", "(10,15]", "(15,20]", "(20,30]", "(30,100]", "(100,200]"
), class = "factor"), eISmedian = c(0, -0.1612095, -4.8167, -4.478417, 
-19.447492, -20.224064), eISmean = c(-2.28172053945819, -6.18051401299694, 
-10.8404419365303, -16.4115004132139, -30.8983449604262, -31.3046641767241
)), .Names = c("advBucket", "eISmedian", "eISmean"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Per the advice of "FascinatingFingers", the below works as expected:

```
orders1 <- full_join(ordersDM, temp1, by = "advBucket")
```

But I still think it's interesting to learn why merge {base} didn't work if anyone is curious.

Comment: Could you make your question fully reproducible? For example, what is `ordersDM`?

Comment: `summarize` is not in any of the default packages. It's in two packages I have loaded and I suspect yours might even be from a third package. What does `identical( levels(ordersDMadvBucket), levels( temp1$advBucket) )` return? Need at a minimum  `dput(head(ordersDMadvBucket))` and `dput(head(temp1))`

Comment: It looks like you may be using `dplyr`? If so, I believe it drops unused factor levels when calling `summarise`. Try using `full_join(ordersDM, temp1)` instead of `base::merge`. I'll bet you get a warning about comparing factors with unequal levels, but then your results look as expected?

Comment: full_join(ordersDM, temp1, by = "advBucket") works as expected, without warning - thank you FascinatingFingers.